# memory allocating a struct

Tags: c, memory, struct

I am new to developing in C. I copied this code from my textbook (Operating Systems by Barak Gonen) into Visual Studio.

I am getting those error messages:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  E0020   identifier "MyStruct" is undefined  Project1
> Error (active)  E0029   expected an expression  Project1
> Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  -> (it suggesting adding the ';' after (MyStruct*) )

Why am I getting those messages and how to solve the problem?
And why am I supposed to allocate memory in C?
How malloc works?

Thank you all for helping !

The code:

```c
struct MyStruct {
  INT a;
  INT b;
};

void main() {
  struct MyStruct * my_struct = (MyStruct * ) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
}
```

Comment: In C, if you don't add `typedef`, it's always `struct MyStruct`. Your type cast is missing `struct`. Add it, or add `typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;`>

Comment: Also, do not cast return value of `malloc`, there is no need to do that in C.

Comment: That is not the whole code being compiled. Nothing in it defines `INT`, and the compiler would complain about that. (Does the original code have `#include "pch.h"`?) Also, either there is a missing `typedef` or the code was intended to be C++ code, because `MyStruct` cannot be used in C after `struct MyStruct` alone, but it can in C++. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including code that can be compiled with no changes or additions to reproduce the messages reported.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not aware of what type `MyStruct` represents in `(MyStruct*) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))` unless you give the custom type a name or explictly state that it is a struct (and this applies to unions as well). You have two options in this case.

1. Explicitly use `struct MyStruct` when refering to the type.

```c
struct MyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
};

[...]

struct MyStruct *my_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct MyStruct));
```

2. Give your custom type a name with the `typedef` keyword at the type definition and use `MyStruct` later on.

```c
typedef struct _MyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
} MyStruct;

[...]

MyStruct *my_struct = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
```